# gettext filter not working on label publish button in edit screen in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, gettext

I don't understand why that filter doesn't work specifically on this button label.

I'm using This filter for change "draft" to "offline" in list pages table :

```
function changement_traduction( $translated ) {
  $words = array('draft' => 'offline');
  $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
  return $translated;
}
 add_filter( 'gettext', 'changement_traduction');
 add_filter( 'ngettext', 'changement_traduction');
```

For change label of publish button filter not working

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the bit for the button text so it's a little difficult to say what's going wrong but I just tested this in a dev environment with the additional button text and it works on pages, post and custom post types:

```
function changement_traduction( $translated ) {
    $words = array(
        'draft' => 'offline',
        'publish' => 'Activate',
        'update' => 'Modify'
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'changement_traduction');
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'changement_traduction');
```

Comment: Sure, i didn't include publish button, it was just for show what working.... If i add "publish" label like your example it does'nt work too.
What other "stuff" can broke this filter ?

Comment: Hmmm, you could try adding a priority like so: add_filter( 'gettext', 'changement_traduction' , 20 , 3); and see if that helps. if not you will likely want to try deactivating plugins one at a time to determine if there is a conflict.